# compilation error while compiling C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, dictionary, find

I am trying to compile a C++ source file but I hit the below error when I try to compile it.

Error :

> error: ‘template class std::map’ used without template parameters

I get the error in the line which has `mp.find(someString)`.

```
map<string, int *> mp;
sub = "xyz";
if(mp.find(sub) != map::end) {  
   doSomething();
}
```

I get the error when the `if` statement is executed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This reference may help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: What part of `template class std::map used without template parameters` needs clarification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `mp.end()` instead of`map::end`

update :

```
if(mp.find(sub) != map::end) {
```

to

```
if(mp.find(sub) != mp.end()) {
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

see [std::map::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) reference

Comment: This documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ 
says that " Searches the container for an element with a key equivalent to k and returns an iterator to it if found, otherwise it returns an iterator to map::end." Hence I used map::end. Should this documentation be changed then?

Comment: It should explained as `If no such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.`

Comment: @bourne There is nothing wrong with the documentation there, it just not very wise to write map::end and excpect it to return the iterator to the end. End of what? What is 'map' anyway ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `mp.end`:

```
 if(mp.find(sub) != mp.end() ) {
```

this reference for [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) shows a more extensive example.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code to :

```
if(mp.find(sub) != mp.end())
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

The `end()` method returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the map container.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/

Maybe you were trying to use `std::end` who is a `C++11` feature :

```
if(mp.find(sub) != std::end(mp))
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In this case, `std::end(mp)` has exactly the same behaviour as `mp.end()`.

Take a look at the documentation : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/